# yfinance not finding ticker closing price

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

This code worked fine before, finding the closing price for every ticker.

Now all tickers return "No price data found, symbol may be delisted (1d 2024-02-01 -> 2024-02-01)"

Has anyone had this issue?

No bug is present, I ran it exactly like this on the 29th and no issue

The xlsx file is just a column with brazilian tickers, nothing more.

```
import openpyxl
import yfinance as yf

file_path ="C:\\Users\\carol\\PycharmProjects\\EXTRATOS\\DOCS\\Fechamento_02_02.xlsx"

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = workbook.active

data = '2024-01-29'

for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    ticker = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value
    if ticker:
        ticker_completo = f"{ticker}.SA"
        print(ticker_completo)

        ativo = yf.Ticker(ticker_completo)
        historico = ativo.history(start=data, end=data)

        preco_fechamento = historico['Close'].iloc[0] if not 
historico.empty else 'N/A'

        sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value = preco_fechamento

workbook.save(file_path)
```

Comment: Please fix formatting

Comment: Okay, now you’re pulling in data from a sheet and not sharing what the data looks like, so we can’t reproduce

Comment: Im very sorry. I added it

Comment: Can you add a ticker that is giving this error?

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code a bit and used a ticker as example:

```
import yfinance as yf

start_date = '2024-01-24'
#end_date = '2024-01-29'
end_date = '2024-02-01'

ticker = "AMZN"
#ticker = "AAPL"
active = yf.Ticker(ticker)
result = active.history(start=start_date, end=end_date)

print(result)
```

If you use a later end date, e.g. '2024-02-01', it works and the data for the 29th January are also contained. However, I get the same error as you do if I use '2024-01-29'. I guess it might be a problem of yahoo finance. But maybe someone has another idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue was resolved by giving a different end date. Not calling the same date. Thank you again